# How to assign a new value to field of all children(obj) in java at one time?

Tags: java, oop, object

Do you have way to assign value of field to all children in easy way?

e.g.

```
Object:Employee
field:salary = 0
children:Employee1,Employee2....
```

How to set all salary field of all Employee

```
EmployeeN.salary = 10000
```

Comment: What does *child object* means?

Comment: Is this a recursive structure?  If so, do you want to set the field on the children's children, etc?

Comment: sorry i'm meanning to children. do you have way to assign all of them at one time

Comment: @user1162226 EmployeeN presumably may have other employees; do you wish to set all of *their* salaries as well?

Comment: @Michael McGowan yes, set all of them at one time don't implement loop. Is it can be possible?

Comment: This is not possible in Java without some sort of loop (one-line or not). You can 'enable' this if you make the field static (a class member), then you can do Employee.salary = 10000 and all the objects see the result. But then you cannot set the salary of a single employee without changing all the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to store all the children in an array and loop over them to give them a value.

Comment: Do you have solution to assign all employee at one time?

Comment: No. You can put the function that you can just call, but there is no magical existing function that can do this in one line.